# Правила написания частиц не или ни.

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Как правильно: "как не пыталась" или "как ни пыталась"?

Comment: пишите более длинный контекст, всю фразу, даже абзац. От этой информации зависит ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно: "как не пыталась" или
> "как ни пыталась"?

Зависит от контекста.

Примеры:

***Как ни пыталась** она распознать в нем тирана, ничего не выходило.*

*— Почему ты не пыталась меня остановить?! **— Как не пыталась?!***

Answer (score 1):

Если этому выражению есть противопоставление (напр. "всё валилось у неё из рук"), то "ни". В противном случае - "не", например:

Как не пыталась она соврать, так не желала и всю правду выкладывать.